# Open new photo in already open Windows Photo Viewer

Tags: windows-7, images, photos, windows-photo-viewer

I would like to find a way to open a specific, random, new image in an already open Windows Photo Viewer window (not to pop a new one with the new picture).

The image files might be in the same folder, but that's not the most important part.

I want to do this in order to create a macro for Windows Speech Recognition Engine, that opens a predefined image, according to the message it gets.

So any way to achieve the above, i.e. terminal or custom script, is acceptable.

Comment: What is a "specific, random, new image"? What have you tried so far? Any research?

Comment: @CharlieRB When I say random (perhaps it's a wrong word here) I mean that I want to define its absolute path, if possible, and it won't be bound by being in the same folder with the image that is already open. What I have tried so far is a risky macro using Picasa, which simulates a series of user actions, clicks and key strokes, that might not always work. And I imagine there must be another way through terminal or with scripts, but I'm not familiar enough with Windows to come up with the right idea myself.

Comment: I think the word you were looking for was "arbitrary". :)  Anyhow, AFAIK you can't reuse WPV's window -- it's not intended to be used like that.  Perhaps use a different image viewer instead.  [See here for similar request](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-US/6baf301e-f02c-4678-ac53-1fe83093af43/windows-photo-viewer-how-to-reuse-existing-windows)

Comment: @techie007 Very Helpful :D thank you.